# Using ng-include with template cache

Tags: angularjs

I am developing in angular js. Previously, i use ng-include with url. But how could i point the url to templatecache?

```
<ng-include
  src="string"
  [onload="string"]
  [autoscroll="string"]>
...
</ng-include>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Template cache uses a key for identifying the cached elements, so you can use the key for that.

```
  $templateCache.put('MY KEY', 'Cached content');
```

And in the html:

```
<ng-include src="'MY KEY'"></ng-include>
```

See it on AngularJS docs for [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache).

Comment: Nice simple example of template cache keys

Comment: This answer helped me understand better how templateCache works and that the key doesn't have to look like a file name.

Comment: How to set URL of the template instead of directly adding HTML in put function?

Comment: There is no use to add the URL of the template, the purpose of the cache if to prevent HTTP requests to fetch the templates. If you want to load all the templates ahead for example, you can use `$http` service to fetch the templates and then store them in the `$templateCache`/

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways:

In markup:

Specify your template as a script tag:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId.html">
  <p>This is the content of the template</p>
</script>
```

(this should be a descendant of your `ng-app`, in other words it should be specified somewhere inside the `ng-app` markup)

This will automatically cache the template.

In code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('templateId.html', 'This is the content of the template');
});
```

In both the cases, you can get the cached template like this:

```
<div ng-include=" 'templateId.html' "></div>
```

or

```
$templateCache.get('templateId.html')
```